# How to call SQL scripts from snowpipe

Tags: sql, sql-scripts, snowsql, snowflake-pipe

I have created a file with multiple DMLs. And then I call that file from `SNOWSQL` client.

Is is possible to do that same via `snowpipe` so that I don't need to call the file manually every time?

Below is the script that I am using in `snowsql` client:

```
snowsql -a <Account> -u <user> -f <Filepath>\Insert.sql -f <Filepath>\Update.sql ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowpipe can be used to Insert the data automatically with below limitations.

1. You can not run Updates.
2. Your data file is arriving at some cloud location.